# Showing info window outside the google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have implemented google map with zip code polygons i.e I am drawing certain zip code polygons over the map using different zip code co-ordinates. Over the zip code polygons I am showing the market markers. When I click  either on the zip code polygon or market marker it displays an info window containing respective data. But this window opens inside the map, pointing to the corresponding zip code/market marker. Now I have a requirement where I have to show the info window outside the map irrespective of the zip code/marker. Like I will keep a certain fixed area(may be div) outside the map, and when I will click any of the zip code polygon, the info window will display inside that fixed area. How can we do it.

**My working code**

```
var path = [
                {% for polycoord in zip.zip_info.zip_polygon %}
                    new google.maps.LatLng({{polycoord.1}}, {{polycoord.0}}),
                {% endfor %}
            ];



var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(
    {
        path:path, 
        clickable:true,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.75,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#333fff',
        fillOpacity: 1,
    }

);



google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) {
            $.ajax({  
                type: "GET",  
                url: GET_DATA,  
                data: dataString, 
                success: function(res) { 
                    if(res != '') {
                        var contentString = res;
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                                        { content: contentString });    
                        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                        infoWindow.open(map);
                        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                            infoWindow.close();
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('No data found')
                    }
                }  
            });
    });
```

Comment: it is possible to get the value and insert it into another div.. could you post your code so that i can have a better look.

Comment: Hi harikrish i have added my working code. Using this code when i click on any zip code area it displays the info window inside the map.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries_simple.html)? (displays the clicked country in a div outside the map...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work (if your existing code does), not tested.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) {
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: GET_DATA,  
            data: dataString, 
            success: function(res) { 
                if(res != '') {
                    var contentString = res;
                    document.getElementById('theIdOfYourDiv').innerHTML = res;
                } else {
                    alert('No data found')
                }
            }  
        });
});
```